# examples of regular schemes

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, regular-rings

Let $Y=\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Z[T]/(T^2+1)$ and $X=\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Z$.
Prove that X and Y are regular.

My attempt:

Denote $\Bbb Z_{p}$ the localisation of $\Bbb Z$ at $p$.

- X is regular:

We know that a PID is regular and that localization of regular ring is regular, so we can immediately state that $\Bbb Z$ is regular and that $\forall p \in Spec\ \Bbb Z: \Bbb Z_{p}$ is regular. Hence $X$ is regular.

But let me try it by hand: $\forall \mathfrak p \in Spec\ \Bbb Z:\Bbb Z_{p}$ is a local ring of maximal ideal $\mathfrak m:=p\Bbb Z_{\mathfrak p}$. Then:

$\dim_{\Bbb F_p} \mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2 = \dim_{\Bbb F_p} p\Bbb Z/p^2\Bbb Z = 1=\dim_{\Bbb F_p}\Bbb Z_{p}$ hence $\Bbb Z_{p}$ is regular and $X$ is regular.

- Y is regular:

I don't know where to start, computations is complicated here and I would need a helping hand.

Thank you.

Comment: The ring $\mathbf Z[T]/(T^2+1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf Z[i]$, which like $\mathbf Z$ is a PID (it is Euclidean with respect to its norm function).

Comment: What about this example where the ring is not principal: $R[T_1,...T_n]/(T_1T_2...T_n - \pi)$ where $\pi$ is the uniformizer of the DVR $R$? Is it correct that $R[T_1,...T_n]/(T_1T_2...T_n - \pi) \cong R[T_1,...T_{n-1}]_{(T_1...T_{n-1})}$ which is just the localization of a regular ring, hence regular?

Comment: What does the notation $R[T_1,...,T_n]_{(T_1...T_{n-1})}$ mean?

Comment: By this notation I meant the localization of the ring $R[T_1,...,T_{n-1}]$ at the ideal $(T_1...T_{n-1})$

Comment: Localizing at an arbitrary ideal does not make sense. You can only localize with respect to a subset $S$ closed under multiplication and not containing zero. What is $S$ in your case? In the classical case $S$ is the complement of a **prime** ideal.